# DynamoDB table not found error using Python and VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using VSCode (on Windows), Python 3.10.5 & AWS. This is just a simple code snippet I cut/pasted directly from the AWS documentation, just to test connectivity to my DynamoDB. I only have 1 table and it's named "VisitorCount".  I have no idea what is going wrong here and so far Google has not been much help.  I do have the AWS Toolkit extension installed, and it does seem to be picking up my creds (although it isn't picking up the Region, which is why I've had to state it explicitly in the code). Can anyone shed a little light on this please?

[Error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPGiw.jpg)

Comment: you need `boto3.resource` not `boto3.client` , `dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name="us-east-1")`

Comment: Always include error messages and code inline in your post, not in an external image.

Comment: @BijayRegmi - that worked.  Oddly enough, I started with that designator - but got account access errors.  Another article pointed to changing it to .client to resolve that error.  Thank you for your response!